# Does avenging the death of a friend kill the general in his game too?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

If I do an avenge mission, and succesfully avenge the death of a friend, is this general then also dead in his game or is this purely an extra mission in my game?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the general isn't dead in their world. They do get an xp bump for being avenged though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been playing the game with two friends and from what we can tell it is only in your game that the general will die. More often than not, the vengeance mission will be against a captain that your friend has already got revenge on too.

But to reiterate, no general ever dropped dead on me when my friend got vengeance on them for me.